# Get user information from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a very easy user management.
I want to select and display the information from the mysql database.

I have connected to the database and it works fine. And I have a log in form and registration which works fine. Now when the user is logged in I want to display the information and the user should be able to update it.

Can i just use a simple thing like this:

```
<?php 
$firstname= $_SESSION['user_name'];
$email= $_SESSION['user_email'];


if ($email!= null) {
echo $email;

}
else {
echo 'no email found';
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it but the thing is that it doesn't seem to be working if there is no result to show.

Comment: Is $email NULL? Empty? *Or is it even set at all?*

Comment: @user259257 You are getting downvoted because your question is way broad and difficult to interpret.  You need to be pretty specific or you'll get downvoted into oblivion quickly, as no one knows how to help you.  I took a guess at what I thought you meant.  Maybe that will encourage you so that you don't give up.

Comment: you mention getting info from db, but theres no db code here.

Comment: Are you sure "nothing to show" is the same as NULL? If not set it could also be ''. Try with if(isset($email)) instead of email!=null

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving a lot out, so it is hard to know what all you want to do, but you can use the `UPDATE` statement to change the database values which have already been inserted.

```
UPDATE users SET user_email = 'some_email'
WHERE user_name = 'some_user';
```

Other than that I'm not sure what you're asking for.  The whole HTML form?

Comment: maybe this is the answer but its just a random guess; why not wait until there's an answerable question posted.

Comment: @Dagon Maybe it will keep the person from being discouraged by all the downvotes that he/she got so quickly.  I am aware of the SO FAQ.  Maybe someone trying something to help might encourage the user to learn and stay at SO and abide in the future by the rules.

Comment: I understand that it was very unclear what I wanted so I will make a couple of tries and then come back with more code and more clear what I want.

Comment: @user259257 I think it will only help you to clarify the exact problem which will point you to the exact question and solution.

Comment: @johnny thank you very much. 
I am very new here and I didn't know everything. But I will be better in the future with questions, answers and comments

Comment: @user259257 I have been downvoted many times.  It can be discouraging.